# AWS PHP SDK cannot use class

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, netbeans-8

I am trying to use the AWS php SDK to upload images from php to S3. However, in Netbeans, I am getting an error while using the code exactly according the examples in the API. What am I doing wrong ? I am using php 5.5 in my project, Netbeans is also configured for php 5.5 in this project. I have installed the SDK without any problems using Composer according to the AWS documentation. I am going home now, but will try and respond tonight.

I am getting a syntax error, saying "Unexpected Identifier".

```
// Include the SDK using the Composer autoloader
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    use Aws\S3\S3Client;
    use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

    // Instantiate the S3 client using your credential profile
    $s3Client = S3Client::factory(array(
    'profile' => 'default',
    ));
```

See these screenshots:

[image]

Comment: What`s the SDK version you using . Is it 3 ?

Comment: also, have you tried "composer dump-autoload"

Comment: Dude, its 2 years later, I dont even carr anymore. But thx !!

Comment: :D :D 
Came across the same issue. Upgrated the SDK and it worked ;)

Answer (score 0):

Update the SDK for version 3.X